# Convert KML to shapefile by ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.5, kmz

I am trying my hand at ModelBuilder today.  This is a simple task; I wish to accomplish this to:

1. Make this task more autonomous
2. Hone my ModelBuilder Skills.

All I'm trying to do is create a simple tool that will allow me to convert a KML/KMZ (or several via batch) to a shapefile which will subsequently allow me  to save the shapefile in the desired folder.  When I attempt to do this process manually I have to convert via 'KML to layer' tool then export layer to shapefile by right clicking "export data" in the TOC and then adding it to the layer.  This process becomes tedious if I have several KMZs.

Can anyone assist?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.

Below is my first attempt which failed miserably.

[image]

Comment: Connect your "output layer" to a FeatureClass to FeatureClass tool, not the FeatureClass to shapefile (multiple) as that is expecting many datasets. You KML to layer tool is only ever creating one output.

Comment: How come you have iterated this selection of mutliple kmls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did in your ModelBuilder is alright, except you forgot to add the only Model tool (Select Data), so you ModelBuilder will be something like that.

[image]

PS: I used (Select Tool) to copy my polygon as shapefile in any folder I want.

The result is the layer (KML to Layer), the geodatabase contains the feature and the result shapefile.

[image]

Then to save your Model as Tool (Just save as > e.g KML_Tool)
Before You need to define the parameters (Input files, outputs) by right click>Model Parameter as shown:

[image]

And save your model. Then it works when you open it.

Comment: where is the 'Select Data' & "select" tool located?

Comment: Model>Insert>Model inly tools>Select Data. for the select tool, you can find in it in the tools box, just search for it and drag it in the model

Comment: Thank you.  Now my final question would be: What and how do I determine what the parameters are?  I created and tried running but didn't have parameters set.

Comment: @Natedawg5509 I didn't understand, which parameters you mean?

Comment: Whenever I lay out the model as depicted in your response, I save the tool to the toolbox.  When I attempt to open the tool, the dialogue box states. "This tool has no parameters."

Comment: @Natedawg5509 I think I got it now, so you want to save this model as a (new tool) in the toolbox?. It’s better to post that as new question with more details, and please toggle this answer as accepted if it solves the model problem.

Comment: Ok I thought the community would understand when I said I was wanting to create a universal tool that allowed me to convert from KML to Shapefile at any given time.  So you suggest I post a new question?

Comment: @Natedawg5509 I updated my answer for the parameters. Sorry, I was confused and thought you are asking something else.

Comment: It worked perfect.  Thank you for your effort! Life just became easier

Comment: @Natedawg5509 you welcome, as I mentioned before that the best way is to toggle the answer as accepted and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

By adding file iterator and according to these steps and pnj attached you can do it.

1- file iterator
2 insert from KMLto layer tool
3 connect  outputs  of file iterator (file and  name ) to "KMLto layer tool"
4- specify  only output folder  in KMLto layer tool